# Question mark before module name

Tags: erlang, elixir

Following this guide: http://relops.com/blog/2014/01/13/leex_and_yecc

```
leex:file('lex')
```

This code generates a module with the name `?LEX` in Erlang, according to the guide. What's the name in Elixir?

Comment: Where does is say that? `?Thing` is a macro substitution in Erlang. There has to be a corresponding `-define(Thing, ...)`.

Comment: I may have misunderstood the post. "where ?LEXER and ?PARSER are the names of the modules generated by leex and yecc respectively." That's still unclear for me, but it describes quite simply what the code I quoted does: "This has converted the lexer grammar into an Erlang module of the same name but with the ending .erl. This can be compiled as a normal Erlang module.

This whole step is done for you if you use the Makefile that is supplied in the project source."

Still new to both Erlang and Elixir, and probably skimmed that post a bit too much.

Answer (score 1):

If you call your file `lexer.xrl`, `leex` will generate an Erlang file called `lexer.erl` that defines a module named `lexer`. You can then use it from Elixir as `:lexer.<function>`. To see the example of this in the article, search for `selector_lexer.xrl`.

It will work similarly with `parser.yrl` – you will get the Erlang module called `parser` which you can invoke as `:parser.<function>` in Elixir.